# How to let each instance of jquery plugin have their own variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this basic plugin, but I want to make it so each instance has it's own variables.

If i run the below, the counter is shared for the two.

How can i make each one have it's own variables?

html

```
<div class=one>one</div>
<br>
<div class=two>two</div>
```

js

```
$.fn.ishare = function(){

    $counter = 0;
    $shell = $(this);

    $shell.on('click',function(){
        console.log($counter++);
    }); 

};


$('.one').ishare('green');

$('.two').ishare('yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like

```
$.fn.ishare = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $counter = 0;
        $(this).on('click',function(){
            console.log($counter++);
        });
    })
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dVLwp/)

Answer (score 0):

With IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). In jQuery plugins is a very good practice. It goes like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.ishare = function() {
var $counter = 0;
$shell = $(this);

$shell.on('click',function(){
    console.log($counter++);
}); 
};
})( jQuery );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aT3wd/

More info here: https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/wiki/How-did-we-get-here%3F

I made my first GitHub jQuery plugin thanks to it.